# How to open common incomplete products link with different toolbar in android studio

Tags: android, webview

I have an eCommerce website and that has been running as an android app using WebView method. I have basic knowledge in android studio but not depth. My concern is wanna open Second Activity from Main Activity when user clicks on any product in app that contains link as "https://www.ecommerce.in/product/XXXXX". Here "https://www.ecommerce.in/product/" is common to all products but "XXXXX" will change to every product when user clicks on different products and this Second Activity should open using another toolbar without related to Main Activity toolbar and my code is like this:

```js
webView.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient()
{
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
  {                    
    if(url.contains("https://www.ecommerce.in/product/XXXXX"))
    {
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductsActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
});
```

This code is not working at all. Hope, I get a solution for this and thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you're trying to filter out links with a contains:

```
if(url.contains("https://www.ecommerce.in/product/XXXXX"))
```

But you've made it too restrictive. It is literally looking for "XXXXX" in the URL. Also, this doesn't really get you much in terms of security. WebViews are very dangerous. I'd suggest looking through this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/android-webview-secure-coding-practices) for some basic suggestions.

Anyways, if you just want to open the `ProductActivity` it looks like all you have to do is update the test as follows:

```
if (url.startsWith("https://www.ecommerce.in/product/"))
```

Note if you need that URL then you have to pass it to the `ProductActivity` as part of the intent and grab it in the `ProductActivity`, but be sure to verify the URL before just loading it to make sure sit starts with the common part.

It might be that someone is trying to get your Activity to do things it shouldn't be.

Comment: Hi @DataDino, I will try and let you know the update on the same.

Comment: Hi @DataDino, sorry to say. No chance, I tried but not working. Any new code..?

Comment: Is it opening the ProductActivity? If not check the value of the `url` field to make sure you are matching correctly. If you are loading the ProductActivity you need to just pass the url using the `Intent` and grab it in the ProductActivity.

Comment: I have done everything as you said but ProductActivity is not opening as new Intent when clicking products. Products are opening from MainActivity only without relating to given code of ProductActivity. Could you please send me written code. It will help me a lot as I have been searching for this but couldn't find proper solution to my problem.